# PhpStorm find in code section

Tags: phpstorm

For example I want search not in all file but only from `100` line to `300` for variable 'instance' at this moment exits any solutions in `PhpStorm` ?

Comment: Make a selection of those lines and use "Find"? It will be plain text search though.

Comment: @LazyOne I not see option 'Find' only 'FInd usage' but this is not same

Comment: You cannot limit "Find Usage" to certain lines -- you may only try to exclude unwanted lines from final report.